# Travel Outside UK Whilst on Garden Leave & Waiting for New Visa Decision

Tags: working-visas, uk-visa

I am currently on garden leave and have a Tier 2 work visa through September 13. My current employer will notify the Home Office that my job has been terminated by September 23. Fortunately, I have a new job offer with visa sponsorship in process. My new employer says they "sent off for my new visa" a few weeks ago. My question is this: can I travel outside the UK on my current visa while waiting for a decision on my new visa? I do not want to put my new visa application at risk by leaving the UK on a holiday.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> You must not travel outside of the UK, Ireland, the Channel Islands or the Isle of Man until you get a decision. Your application will be withdrawn if you do.

Source: [Skilled Worker Visa *Update your visa if you change job or employer*](https://www.gov.uk/skilled-worker-visa/update-your-visa-if-you-change-job-or-employer)